# How to track the URL page which customers use my form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, url

i have a website with many villa properties and i have import a button "Ask for Better Price" that opens a popup with a form inside that have some fields (like: name,surname etc) i need

somehow when someone complete and submit that form to come along with the details that he complete the which url was?

i have online upload there the form http://www.connectaxweb.gr/svform/property_header.html and i was use that files: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C388305F9D87CC98!46170&authkey=!APkE57lKWwc-BEQ&ithint=folder%2cphp

Comment: Which URL you want to track ?

Comment: that exactly i havent one or two pages, that form it will automatically show in many properties, thats why i need somehow to show me from which url comes any submit